# If I'm using the Form of the Exotic Dragon III spell, do I get the Crush special attack?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, attack, wild-shape

I have a quick question for a Pathfinder 1e campaign.

If I'm using Form of the Exotic Dragon III, do I get the Crush special attack?

There's nothing stating I do in the spell, per se, but Wild Shape lets you typically get the special attacks of the creatures, and we're creating a homebrew helm that lets me Wild Shape into a dragon, similar to the Mask of Giants. I also have Powerful Shape. So as a huge dragon, I'll be a colossal one based on my size, so hypothetically, I can do a Tail Sweep attack because Powerful Shape focuses on special attacks.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. In general, [you should ask only one question per post](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6453/33569). I've edit your secondary question out of this post; if you have a separate question, you should [ask about it separately](/questions/ask) instead.

Answer (score 3):

If using [Form of the Exotic Dragon III](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/form-of-the-exotic-dragon/), you don't get a Crush attack:

> You gain one bite attack (2d8), two claw attacks (2d6), a one tail slap attack (2d6), and [...] two wing attacks (1d8)[...].

You generally don't get anything the spell doesn't say you do, as per the [Polymorph subschool](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic/#Transmutation) rules:

> Polymorph: a polymorph spell transforms your physical body to take on the shape of another creature. [...] they do not grant you all of the abilities and powers of the creature. Each polymorph spell allows you to assume the form of a creature of a specific type, granting you a number of bonuses to your ability scores and a bonus to your natural armor. In addition, each polymorph spell can grant you a number of other benefits, including movement types, resistances, and senses. If the form you choose grants these benefits, or a greater ability of the same type, you gain the listed benefit. If the form grants a lesser ability of the same type, you gain the lesser ability instead. Your base speed changes to match that of the form you assume. If the form grants a swim or burrow speed, you maintain the ability to breathe if you are swimming or burrowing. The DC for any of these abilities equals your DC for the polymorph spell used to change you into that form.

As far as I'm aware, both Crush and Tail Sweep are listed as special, Extraordinaire abilities, so the answer is no, you don't get those.

Of course, since you're already veering into Homebrew, your DM may decide differently. And you are, because normally Druids don't get to wild shape into dragons, nor into the highest tier of any of the polymorph spells.

And while it's technically a different question, you can't grab Snatch either. It requires your base form to be Huge to take, aside from already requiring GM greenlighting for being a Monster feat. You could offer that it only works when your current shape is Huge, if your GM is worried about balance.

Though again, that's houserules, and not permitted by the rules as written.

Comment: Good points, I'll let my GM decide. He's pretty fair, and is all about the RP of it, so if he thinks it'll make for good storytelling, he might. Especially with the idea that the Snatch feat is only useful in Wild Shape form. Thanks!